# How to mention user/page in post on wall using facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've found format

@[id:1:anchor]

where id is user id or page id and anchor is text displayed. 
This format is not documented on official facebook dev page, thus working.

What is the status of issue? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to let users tag their friends in a Facebook status update posted from a tab on a Facebook page?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4186795/how-to-let-users-tag-their-friends-in-a-facebook-status-update-posted-from-a-tab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to add tags in text this way via the API. There were loopholes which allowed this to work but they were closed shortly afterwards

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution for this, here the using c# code:

```
protected void btnPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var client = new FacebookClient("YOUR FB TOKEN HERE");
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                { 
                     {"message", "YOUR STATUS HERE" },
                     {"tags" , "YOUR FRIENDS FB ID HERE"},
                     {"place" , "YOUR PLACE ID HERE"}
                };
    client.Post("me/feed", parameters);
    lblPost.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    lblPost.Text = "Status Updated!";
```